# Undefined index pero el índice está definido

Tags: php, sql

Aclaro que no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre PHP ya que hace poco comencé a usarlo. Tengo una REST API desarrollada en PHP y por alguna razón me da el error `Undefined index: turnoActual in C:\wamp64\www\Examen.php on line 56`. Observando el código y realizando varias pruebas pude observar lo siguiente:

Mi Examen.php:

```
$colegio = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'colegio');
$codigo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'codigo');
$curso = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'curso');
$materia = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'materia');
$clectivo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'clectivo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
$examenDao = new ExamenDao();

$cierres = $examenDao->cierreExamenes($colegio);
    
$tExamen = $examenDao->obtenerTurnoExamen($colegio, $clectivo);
    
$turnoExamen = $tExamen["turnoActual"];
    
$datosExamen = $examenDao->validacionInscripcion($colegio, $codigo, $curso, $materia, $turnoExamen);
```

La variable `$tExamen` devuelve como valor algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que claramente la variable `turnoActual` está definida, pero a la hora de querer asignarla me da error como si fuera inexistente. Aclaro que está conectado con una web dinámica y estoy utilizando PHP 5.6.40 en el servidor local hosteado por WAMP ya que en esa versión fue desarrollado. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias!

var_dump:

```
C:\wamp64\www\Examen.php:79:
array (size=4)
  'turnoActual' => string '122021' (length=6)
  'nombre' => string 'NOVIEM/DICIEM. ' (length=15)
  'fecha_de' => string '2021-10-01' (length=10)
  'fecha_ha' => string '2021-12-31' (length=10)
```

Función obtenerTurnoExamen:

```
public function obtenerTurnoExamen($codigo, $clectivo) {

        $query = "SELECT concat(turno, c_lectivo) as turnoActual, nombre, fecha_de, fecha_ha FROM turnexa WHERE colegio = ? AND nivel = 'T' AND clectivo = ? AND (curdate() >= fecha_de AND curdate() <= fecha_ha)";

        $tipo = 'si';
        $respuesta = $this->consultaRegistroArrayParam($query, [&$tipo, &$codigo, &$clectivo]);

        if (empty($respuesta)) {
            return [];
        } else {
            return $respuesta;
        }
    }
```

Es muy raro ya que difieren la respuesta que me da JavaScript con la que me da PostMan

Comment: Cual es el var_dump($tExamen) ??

Comment: ¿Y no será un objeto?  ¿Has probado con `$tExamen->turnoActual`?

Comment: @masterguru Hola, no, es un array, ya que queriendo hacer eso que especificas me da error y me dice que es un array

Comment: nunca dije que lo pusieras en el comentario ... dije en la publicacion.

Comment: Listo @Excorpion, disculpa por las molestias

Comment: Si la variable tExamen es un array de objetos como muestras en la imagen, ¿no sería posible acceder al elemento usando $turnoExamen = $tExamen[0]["turnoActual"]; ? Reemplazando 0 por el índice del turno que corresponde. El error indica `Undefined index: turnoActual` entonces si es un array debes obtener el elemento del índice apropiado y luego buscar la propiedad turnoactual.

Comment: @MarceloZárate Hola, te cuento, ese error me lo lanza chrome desde el inspector, sospecho que tiene algo que ver el JavaScript de la página, ya que cuando hago las mismas request pero desde postman, todo devuelve lo que debería

Comment: @Excorpion Listo!! :)

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP el tema no es no leer, es como resolverlo.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Hola, yo se cual es el problema, por algo estoy acá preguntando específicamente como resolverlo....

Comment: lo que obtienes es un warning por que PHP lo pudo corregir osea que el forzo la asignacion ... pero antes de usar `$tExamen["turnoActual"];` debe estar declarado, no veo esto ultimo `$tExamen["turnoActual"]= 'Valor';`

Comment: ¿En la tabla `turnexa` tienes estas dos columnas `c_lectivo` y `clectivo`?

Comment: @Triby sisi, las tengo, tengo todas las tablas a las que hace referencia, por eso no entiendo el error

Answer (score 1):

Si desde tu cliente REST obtienes esto:

[image: respuesta postman]

El problema es que no puedes asignar `$tExamen["turnoActual"];`

¿Por qué? pues por lo que dice el error `Undefined index:` el índice turnoActual para la variable tExamen on existe.

```
[
    {
        "turnoActual": "12****",
        "nombre": "NOVIEM\/DICIEM. ",
        "fecha_de": "2021-10-01",
        "fecha_de": "2021-12-31",
    }
]
```

¡Pero si yo ahí la veo a turno actual!

Claro, pero ves la propiedad del **primer** objeto de ese array. Si intentas hacer $tExamen[0]

```
    {
        "turnoActual": "12****",
        "nombre": "NOVIEM\/DICIEM. ",
        "fecha_de": "2021-10-01",
        "fecha_de": "2021-12-31",
    }
```

obtendrás entonces el objeto al que sí puedes acceder a sus propiedades usando ["turnoActual"]

por tanto para acceder, deberías usar `$tExamen[0]["turnoActual"];`

Comment: Hola, si yo aplico los cambios que vos especificas obtengo este error `Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\Examen.php on line 56`, y cuando quito el [0] el error desaparece, por lo que doy por entendido que lo que estoy haciendo está bien, pero no sé

Comment: ¿puedes indicar en la pregunta cuál es la línea 56 de `Examen.php`?

Comment: La linea 56 es la que asigna `$turnoExamen = $tExamen["turnoExamen"];`

Comment: Antes de esa línea escribe `var_dump($tExamen);` ¿qué te devuelve?

Comment: @MarceloZárate ya está en la pregunta! :)

Comment: Lo siento bro, pero es que el error es de la línea `56` y el dump de la línea `79`, por eso quería asegurarme de que esté haciendo dump en la línea correcta sin tener todo el código para poder verlo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132700/discussion-between-marcelo-zarate-and-luca-viotti).

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que el método `obtenerTurnoExamen()` puede devolver el resultado de la consulta o un arreglo vacío en caso de no encontrar el turno, entonces debes asegurarte de que hayas recibido un valor adecuado:

```
$examenDao = new ExamenDao();
$cierres = $examenDao->cierreExamenes($colegio);
$tExamen = $examenDao->obtenerTurnoExamen($colegio, $clectivo);
// Verificar el valor
if(empty($tExamen)) {
    // Esto es solo un ejemplo, deberías capturar el error
    // y enviarlo al usuario para que sepa lo que pasó
    die('No se encontró el turno.');
}
$turnoExamen = $tExamen["turnoActual"];
$datosExamen = $examenDao->validacionInscripcion($colegio, $codigo, $curso, $materia, $turnoExamen);
```

Con base en la consulta:

```
SELECT concat(turno, c_lectivo) as turnoActual, nombre, fecha_de, fecha_ha
FROM turnexa
WHERE colegio = ? AND nivel = 'T' AND clectivo = ? AND (curdate() >= fecha_de AND curdate() <= fecha_ha)
```

Me da la impresión de que podría generar error, a menos que tengas dos columnas muy similares en la tabla: `c_lectivo` y `clectivo`

Comment: Haciendolo así si funciona, pero de todas formas siempre va por el camino del error, por así decirlo

Comment: @LucaViotti Como es eso ?? Está mal lo de Triby ?? en que ?

Comment: Osea, siempre va por el mismo camino, yo hice algo como esto:
`if(!empty($tExamen))
                $turnoExamen = $tExamen["turnoActual"];
            else
                $turnoExamen = 0;`
solo para probar, y cuando llega al front, `$turnoExamen` siempre vale 0, por lo que no es una solucion que me sirva

Comment: @LucaViotti, entonces hay algo mal en la consulta o en el flujo del programa. Si no existe el turno para el colegio, no deberías permitir continuar y verificar porqué no devuelve el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, tengo mi teoría... imprimiendo tu var_dump() anteriormente preguntado... obtengo exactamente esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, posteriormente lanza un NULL...

Me pregunté porque, y pedi tu función, en donde veo esta situación...

```
if (empty($respuesta)) {
    return [];
} else {
    return $respuesta;
}
```

Entonces, mi teoría es que retornas 2 o más veces las cosas, por eso hay uno llego, luego uno null, entonces al tratar de leer, el indice, estás leyendo el null.

Comment: Gracias por todo el esfuerzo, desde ya, creo que el `null` que ves ahí, es porque el `return` de la función estaba devolviendo un null, no sabía que `var_dump()` ejecutaba un return también entonces quedo de forma "residual" el valor null

Comment: Revisa de todos modos, y actualiza la publicación (esta vez lo dije) una vez obtengas un mejor resultado, pero no el NULL.